# Match and compare two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to compare two tables in a database. They do store similar info. 
However in some cases `ID` and `Segment` (`SUBSTRING (data, 1, 1)`) do match, however the Service Number and Service date are different for each `ID`.

Here is my example data. In this case the two highlighted rows should be selected:

[image: Example data]

I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
    T.ID, 
    SUBSTRING(data, 1, 1) AS Seg, 
    SUBSTRING(data, 2, 4) AS sn, 
    CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(data, 11, 8)), 
    ServiceNumber, ServiceDate
FROM
    P
JOIN 
    T ON p.ID = t.ID
WHERE
    SUBSTRING(data, 1, 1) != Segment
    AND SUBSTRING(data, 2, 4) != ServiceNumber
    AND CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(data, 11, 8)) != ServiceDate;
```

The SQL Fiddle link is here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d6aee/10

Any ideas would be more then welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is an error in your pasted example, viz that the second row shouldn't be highlighted as the ID, Segments and the Date are the same, you can simplify the problem by breaking out the encoded column into its components with a CTE or derived table, and then ease the comparison:

```
WITH FixedTableP AS
(
     SELECT P.ID,
            SUBSTRING ( [data] ,1 , 1 ) AS PSegment,
            SUBSTRING( [data] ,2 , 4 ) AS PServiceNumber,
            CONVERT(date,SUBSTRING ( data ,11 , 8 )) AS PServiceDate
     FROM P
)
SELECT T.ID, P.ID, T.ServiceNumber, P.PServiceNumber, T.ServiceDate, P.PServiceDate
FROM T
JOIN FixedTableP P ON p.ID=t.ID AND p.PSegment = t.Segment
WHERE P.PServiceDate <> T.ServiceDate 
      AND P.PServiceNumber <> T.ServiceNumber;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f1ace/3)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want select only the difference?

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ID, 
    CAST(SUBSTRING ( data ,1 , 1 ) AS INT) AS Seg, 
    CAST(LTRIM(SUBSTRING ( data ,2 , 4 )) AS VARCHAR(25)) AS sn, 
    CONVERT(date,SUBSTRING ( data ,11 , 8 )) AS ServiceDate
from P
)
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM cte c 
    WHERE c.ID = t.ID
    AND c.Seg = t.Segment
    AND c.sn = t.ServiceNumber
    AND c.ServiceDate = t.ServiceDate)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d6aee/30

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to do, but try this.

Assuming the amount of characters in the columns are consistent.

```
SELECT T.ID, 
SUBSTRING ( data ,1 , 1 ) AS Seg, 
SUBSTRING ( data ,2 , 4 ) AS sn, 
CONVERT(date,SUBSTRING ( data ,11 , 8 )), ServiceNumber, ServiceDate
FROM T
INNER JOIN P ON T.SERVICENUMBER = SUBSTRING(P.DATA,2,3) 
            AND T.SERVICENUMBER = RIGHT(P.DATA,7)
WHERE P.ID = T.ID
```